# Laravel 5.1 - HHVM - S3Exception in WrappedHttpHandler.php line 152

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3

After upgrading to Laravel 5.1 from 5.0, I'm having problems with AWS S3.

I created a test route to verify that S3 was working and it seems that is is not:

```
get('/test', function() {
   return Storage::disk('s3')->exists('temp/file.jpg') ? 'true' : 'false';
});
```

The following error is returned:

```
S3Exception in WrappedHttpHandler.php line 152:
Error executing "HeadObject" on "https://s3.amazonaws.com/rugapp/temp/file.jpg"; AWS HTTP error: Client error response [url] https://s3.amazonaws.com/app/temp/file.jpg [status code] 403 [reason phrase] Forbidden (client): 403 Forbidden
```

After doing some research, it seems this issue may or may not be related to HHVM. I am using Laravel Homestead which runs the following:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- PHP 5.6
- HHVM
- Nginx

After reading [this](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/620), I upgraded HHVM to 3.8-dev and restarted Nginx.  The problem remained.

Does anyone have any insight on how to resolve this problem?

UPDATE:  It seems to work fine now but I'm not sure why.  I haven't made any changes overnight.  Strange.

Comment: Either your HEAD request is not signed or is incorrectly signed.

Comment: Have you tried get btw? can show stacktrace?

Comment: Have you already give permission to your storage?

Comment: Storage permissions have been set and using the storage facade for the local disk works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar issue happens in my local homestead development while my app running on Linode works fine.

After checking S3 permission, checked out old version, etc., this problem disappear when I restart homestead.

```
homestead halt
homestead up --provision
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error.  I believe it happened because I switched wireless networks as I was developing.  After restarting the virtual machine, the error went away.